# Doctrine2 Association Entities are not removed

Tags: doctrine-orm, associations

currently I have a problem with Doctrine2 when using two Entities and map them with an own Association Entity. I exactly copied the Entity classes like in this blog post here: http://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/doctrine-2-how-to-handle-join-tables-with-extra-columns/

In my example, I have used a PHPUnit Test where I play the scenario in the following way. But the difference to the blog post is, that my association entity is not removed! The phpunit testcase fails, where I expect that the company has only one job left and person two none.

This happened to me in my own project and I tried to get the example right and map it afterwards to my case, but also the example does not work. Were there any changes to doctrine that prevents removing the association entity?

```
$entityManager     = $this->entityManager;
$personRepository  = $entityManager->getRepository(Person::class);
$companyRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(Company::class);

// Setup the person and company
$person = new Person();
$person->setName('Person 1');

$company = new Company();
$company->setName('Company 1');

$entityManager->persist($person);
$entityManager->persist($company);
$entityManager->flush();


// Create the job to connect Person 1 and Company 1
$job = new Job();
$job->setStartedOn(new \DateTime('01-10-2009'))
    ->setMonthlySalary(10000);

$person->addJob($job);
$company->addJob($job);
$entityManager->flush();


// Assert that both the company and the person have one job
$entityManager->clear();

/* @var $person Person */
$person = $personRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);

/* @var $company Company */
$company = $companyRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);

$this->assertCount(1, $person->getJobs());
$this->assertCount(1, $company->getJobs());


// Add another person to the company
$person = new Person();
$person->setName('Person 2');

$job = new Job();
$job->setStartedOn(new \DateTime('16-02-2006'))
    ->setMonthlySalary(10000); // He wishes!

$person->addJob($job);
$company->addJob($job);
$entityManager->persist($person);
$entityManager->flush();


// Assert that the company now has two jobs and each person one
$entityManager->clear();

/* @var $personOne Person */
$personOne = $personRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);

/* @var $personTwo Person */
$personTwo = $personRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 2]);

/* @var $company Company */
$company = $companyRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);

$this->assertCount(2, $company->getJobs());
$this->assertCount(1, $personOne->getJobs());
$this->assertCount(1, $personTwo->getJobs());


// Now remove the job from the Person Two
$job = $person->getJobs()[0];
$personTwo->removeJob($job);
$entityManager->flush();


// Assert that the company now has one jobs and person two none
$entityManager->clear();

/* @var $personOne Person */
$personOne = $personRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);

/* @var $personTwo Person */
$personTwo = $personRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 2]);

/* @var $company Company */
$company = $companyRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);

$this->assertCount(1, $company->getJobs());
$this->assertCount(1, $personOne->getJobs());
$this->assertCount(0, $personTwo->getJobs());
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I think the article may be a bit misleading or perhaps even incorrect.  Explicitly remove the job from both the person and the company and see what happens.

Comment: Even with `$personTwo->removeJob($job); $company->removeJob($job);` the actual size of the jobs is still 2 and not the expected 1 :-(

Comment: You will need to do an explicit $em->remove($job);  The cascading stuff is only going to work if you remove the person or company entity.